# replacement missing values by groups in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

How can i replace the missing values for each group separately?

The reproducible example:

```
mydata=structure(list(group1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), group.2 = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), x1 = c(20L, 4L, 91L, NA, 94L, 69L, 38L, 
NA, 29L, 69L, 55L, 86L, 81L, 11L, NA, 12L, 65L, 90L, 74L, NA, 
49L, 90L), x2 = c(44L, 94L, NA, 1L, 67L, NA, 73L, 22L, 44L, 24L, 
NA, 54L, 70L, 65L, 97L, 10L, 97L, NA, 74L, 97L, 34L, 29L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

Now i found how to replace the missing values without groups.

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("x1")), funs(ifelse(is.na(.) & is.numeric(.) ,mean(., na.rm = TRUE),.)))
```

But i need to replace for each groups (group1,group2) separately.

## edit to small dataset

```
structure(list(group1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), group.2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), x1 = c(63L, 67L, 57L, NA, 65L, 75L, 57L, 80L, 42L, 
NA, 35L, 80L), x2 = c(46L, 1L, NA, 41L, 80L, NA, 74L, 73L, NA, 
13L, 83L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: You want x1 missing values to be replaced by the corresponding means of x1 by group1 and x2 missing values to be replaced by the corresponding means of x2 by group2? It's better if you create an example on a smaller dataset with your ideal output to make it more clear.

Comment: @AntoniosK, replacing must be for group1+group2

Comment: So, you're grouping by both? Like having one grouping variable as {1,1}, {1,2}, {2,1}, {2,2}.?

Comment: @AntoniosK yes, you are right , i edited post with small dataset

Comment: I think I got what you want to do but I'm not sure. Check my answer below and see if that's your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydata=structure(list(group1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), group2 = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), x1 = c(20L, 4L, 91L, NA, 94L, 69L, 38L, 
NA, 29L, 69L, 55L, 86L, 81L, 11L, NA, 12L, 65L, 90L, 74L, NA, 
49L, 90L), x2 = c(44L, 94L, NA, 1L, 67L, NA, 73L, 22L, 44L, 24L, 
NA, 54L, 70L, 65L, 97L, 10L, 97L, NA, 74L, 97L, 34L, 29L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))


library(tidyverse)

mydata %>%
  unite(group, group1, group2) %>%        # combine groups
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%           # add the row number as an id (useful when reshaping)
  gather(var, value, -group, -id) %>%     # reshape data
  group_by(group, var) %>%                # for each group combination and variable
  mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value), mean(value, na.rm = T), value)) %>%   # replace NAs with mean
  spread(var, value) %>%                  # reshape again
  arrange(id) %>%                         # keep order of original dataset
  select(-id) %>%                         # remove id
  ungroup() %>%                           # forget the grouping
  separate(group, c("group1","group2"))   # split the groups again

# # A tibble: 22 x 4
#   group1 group2    x1    x2
#   <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 1      1       20    44  
# 2 1      2        4    94  
# 3 1      1       91    61.3
# 4 1      2       36.5   1  
# 5 1      1       94    67  
# 6 1      2       69    39  
# 7 1      1       38    73  
# 8 1      2       36.5  22  
# 9 2      1       29    44  
# 10 2      2       69    24  
# # ... with 12 more rows
```